# Android NDK joystick events

Tags: event-handling, android-ndk, joystick

Does anyone know how to capture joystick events from the Android NDK?

The NDK does not contain any APIs to let me extract axis information from an AMotionEvent. (AXIS_X and AXIS_Y are mapped to the pointer (x,y) pair, but I need more than that.) There are Java APIs to do this... but when I'm using the NDK, events aren't delivered to Java-land, so I simply never receive them.

And I haven't found any way to turn an NDK AMotionEvent into a Java MotionEvent so that I can pass it through to Java via JNI and extract the information that way.

I absolutely have to get joystick information to my app, but so far I've found no way to do so, no matter how evil. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The people at Nvidia Tegra have managed to do this by using an undocumented function call.
They do an dlopen and a dlsym on libandroid.so to look for AMotionEvent_getAxisValue()

```
void* lib = dlopen("libandroid.so",0);
...
s_AMotionEvent_getAxisValue = (float(*)(const AInputEvent*,int32_t axis, size_t pointer_index))
        dlsym(lib,"AMotionEvent_getAxisValue");
```

For more information, you should consult nvidias android samples in [Tegra Android Development Pack](https://developer.nvidia.com/tegra-android-development-pack)

Comment: Thank-you! Yes, this works fine. (I actually found it out elsewhere earlier but forgot to update my question. Thanks the prompt.)